# Make background image fit at full screen (not window) and size not change when minimizing window without using px

Tags: css, reactjs, layout, background-image, fixed

I didn't find how to make a fixed background image when you first create a react app.
I will explain:
When i do the commands :
npx create-react-app reactapp
cd reactapp
npm start

I see the default react app that is on local host 3000 and react logo that spins.
And when I am trying to add background image in html or body or app.js div,
The background image shrinks when i minimize my window.
I tried height with % vh vw rem rm and so far. Only px worked for me but I don't want to use px because it doesn't fit at the whole screen. 
So if someone please can tell me where I should add the background image and make the website layout fixed (make the content in the window not shrinking when minimizig).
Thank you!

css files :
[index.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLbKp.png)

[app.css part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFCHQ.png)
[app.css part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EULTf.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly use a `%` instead of a `px` you need to set a position property for the background. You can try to set `position: relative;` to the html element that contains your background image and then set its `width` and `height` with `%`. I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: I said that I have tried using % but still the content in the window shrink when i minimize the window.

Comment: Ok so maybe the problem is image sizes. When you use % it fits 100% of its original width which is not equal to your window size width. That is why when you use px it works because it changes original image sizes. Maybe you need to change image size using editor and make them equal to window size?

Comment: If it doesn't work try to use height with px and width: unset; or try width: 100% !important;

Comment: You still don't understand. When i use 100% it does fit on all window but when i minimize my window the image also minimize with it. I can solve it by using px but then it will not be appropriate on each screen. I want to use dynamic image that the size is changing by the screen size and not by the window size.

Comment: Alright then maybe you can try to put @media queries for each screen size and use px on all of them ?

Comment: But there is must be a generic way to do this without using px. With media queries i still using px.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if I can see other way then. Did you tried  to add the background image to body element instead of html?

Comment: I don't have anymore ideas for now. Sorry :(

Comment: the only thing I can suggest then is to look in bootstrap for some solutions that may help